# Get drive letter from filename in Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, filesystems, drive-letter

Is there a Windows API function to extract the drive letter from a Windows path such as

```
U:\path\to\file.txt
\\?\U:\path\to\file.txt
```

while correctly sorting out

```
relative\path\to\file.txt:alternate-stream
```

etc?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[PathGetDriveNumber](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773612%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) returns 0 through 25 (corresponding to 'A' through 'Z') if the path has a drive letter, or -1 otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

Here is code that combines the accepted answer (thanks!) with `PathBuildRoot` to round out the solution

```
#include <Shlwapi.h>    // PathGetDriveNumber, PathBuildRoot
#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")

/** Returns the root drive of the specified file path, or empty string on error */
std::wstring GetRootDriveOfFilePath(const std::wstring &filePath)
{
// get drive #      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773612(v=vs.85).aspx
int drvNbr = PathGetDriveNumber(filePath.c_str());

if (drvNbr == -1)   // fn returns -1 on error
    return L"";

wchar_t buff[4] = {};   // temp buffer for root 

// Turn drive number into root      http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773567(v=vs.85)
PathBuildRoot(buff,drvNbr);

return std::wstring(buff);  
}
```

Comment: Thanks - two comments: you don't need to copy the array pointer, just use the array itself as the parameter to `PathBuildRoot`. And, if you want to initialize a static array, just use `= {}` because this is the general solution and works for all types and sizes.

Comment: @FelixDombek:  fixed, thanks!  This is cleaner, I like it.  I'm still fairly new to C++, your feedback is appreciated

Comment: That's cool. Then you might be interested to know that you can (almost) always use `buff` to mean the same thing as `&buff[0]` for static arrays. Works for function calls, returns, etc. (see http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html, arrays decay into pointers in expressions **except** when the array is the operand of a `sizeof` or `&` operator which is not the case here)

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your requirements, you might also want to consider [GetVolumePathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the mount point, which may or may not be a drive letter.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{    
    string aux;
    cin >> aux;
    int pos = aux.find(':', 0);
    cout << aux.substr(pos-1,1) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's the Windows API function? :P

Comment: @m0skit0: your function doesn't work if it's a relative path with an alternate NTFS stream ;)

Comment: I used the examples you provided since I'm not very experienced working with Windows :)