# Identify the drive of a program on Windows

Tags: c++, wmic, serial-number

I have a Windows program coded in C++. To get the drive's serial number of the computer's drive, I run "wmic path win32_physicalmedia get SerialNumber" in the program with _popen().

However, the computers that run the program may have many drives, and USB drives also appear in the list.

How can I do to know which of the drives has the program I'm running? Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get drive letter from filename in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7122009/get-drive-letter-from-filename-in-windows)

Comment: @GáborBakos not dupe, OP is searching for physical drive serial number given a path name. To get drive letter from file name is just second step of this job.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you still want to do it with WMI: first of all you need some code to read WMI properties in C++. No need to repeat here, you can find it in [Getting CPU ID code from C# to be in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10229673/1207195).

When you have that code you can stat to work with disks. First of all you need to remember how Windows organize disks:

- Each physical disk (`Win32_DiskDrive`) is made by partitions (`Win32_DiskPartition`).
- Each partition (`Win32_DiskPartition`) is a logical disk (`Win32_LogicalDisk`).
- Mapping between each other is done with `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` and `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition`.

You already know [where you're running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1108089/1207195) then you can do this mapping:

Fetch from `Win32_LogicalDisk` the one where `DeviceID` property matches drive you're running on:

```
DeviceID=C:
```

Query `Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition` and pick `Antecedent` for which `Dependent` has ID you previously found:

```
\\REPETTI\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #1"  \\REPETTI\root\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID="C:"
```

Now you should query partitions in `Win32_DiskPartition` to find the one where `DeviceID` is `Disk #1, Partition #1` however also `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` uses `DeviceID` for this mapping then you can directly query `Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition` to match given ID:

```
\\REPETTI\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID="\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1"  \\REPETTI\root\cimv2:Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID="Disk #1, Partition #1"
```

Now you just need to query `Win32_DiskDrive` searching for device ID `\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1`:

```
WDC WDxxx ATA Device  \\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1  WDC WDxxx ATA Device
```

And you can get its serial number (in this case same property is available both in `Win32_PhysicalMedia` and `Win32_DiskDrive` otherwise you should search by its `Caption`).

**Without WMI**

If you have to do it without WMI then it's *little bit* more tricky.

- First of all you need to figure out which physical drive contains your logical drive_ you may follow [How to list physical disks?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11683906/1207195).
- When you have physical drive name easiest way is `CreateFile()` to open drive and get information with `DeviceIoControl()` sending S.M.A.R.T. commands. Don't think it's always so easy: with many drives it'll fail and you need administrative rights. Unfortunately there isn't a single perfect solution then you need to *try* different approaches. AFAIK best and most exhaustive code to handle this is written by Lynn McGuire for its [DiskId32](https://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.html) utility.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the "\\REPETTI\root" lines, but anyway, I used the WMI commands you listed like this:.

Comment: It's computer name (Repetti, in my domain). If you run same queries you will get another name

Comment: Thanks! I didn't understand the "\\REPETTI\root" lines, but I used the WMI commands you listed:

1. Call "GetModuleFileNameW()" to get the partition letter (for example 'C').
2. Call "wmic logicaldisk where (DeviceID="C:") assoc /assocclass:Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition" to get the partition id ("Disk #0, Partition #1").
3. Call "wmic partition where (DeviceID="Disk #0, Partition #1") assoc /assocclass:Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" to get the physical drive id ("\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0").
4. Call "wmic path win32_diskdrive get deviceid, serialnumber" to get the serial numbers, and search by id.

Comment: Right, at first sight that's it!